# What is the Cloud9 keyboard shortcut for the terminal?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cloud9-ide

What is the cloud9 keyboard shortcut to move between the editor tab (#1) and the terminal console (#2)?

I am aware that I can open a terminal tab and switch to it using the keyboard, but I want to see both the editor and terminal in one view.

[image: Cloud9 screenshot showing Editor (1) and Console (2)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Shift+ESC on open source, but unfortunately this doesn't work on c9.io.

Answer (score 11):

It is <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> on the current version of Cloud9

Answer (score 6):

To make certain keyboard shortcut work on [c9.io](https://c9.io) in Chrome, which would otherwise do something else like close tab or reload page, click the `menu button of Chrome` > `More Tools` > `Create Application Shortcuts...`.

Now the IDE is an actual program and all the default browser shortcuts are disabled. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (Close tab) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> (Close Chrome) and  <kbd>F5</kbd> (Refresh) and the likes can now be used as keyboard shortcuts :)

Answer (score 4):

To add on [@Kronenbourg's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29032289/293974) exact answer (which IMHO should be accepted) - as of May 2015:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> / <kbd>Esc</kbd> - Goto workspace (files tree) / Exit workspace (to the last place, Editor/Terminal)
- <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> - switch between code and terminal

In conjunction with <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd> / <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd>, which navigate right/left in current context (Editor, terminal) tabs, you should be able to reach anywhere with the keyboard.

Also useful in the context is <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to open file.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

I accidentally found out that `ctrl`+`~` works to switch between terminal and editing window and then back. Maybe it's not the most convenient shortcut but it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Alt+s**

This shortcut is listed in the top menu, under:
Window > Navigation